# How to implement pause and delete typewriter effect in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

new to JS here and was wondering if someone could guide me on how I can pause and delete when implementing a typewriter effect in JavaScript.
I've got a function that successfully types out each word in an array, however I would like it to pause after typing each word and backspace or delete the letters before typing the next one.

```js
//counter
var i = 0;
var index = 0;
var texts = ['Salesforce Consultant', 'Developer', 'Writer'];
var speed = 110;
let letter = '';
let currentText = '';
let delay = 25;

function typeWriter() {

  //If counter is less than the # of letters in txt, reset array of words
  if (i === texts.length) {
    i = 0;
  }

  //Use count to select text to display
  currentText = texts[i];
  letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);


  document.querySelector("#demo").textContent = letter;

  //If letters displayed are the same number of letters in the current text
  if (letter.length === currentText.length) {

    //Pause before deleting

    //Delete letters in word

    //Word is done displaying, and reset letters on screen
    i++;

    index = 0;

  }
  setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

HTML

```
    <div class="centered">
    <div class="intro">
        <p>A &thinsp;</p> 
        <p class ="typing" id="demo"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added the section that references the 'id' in the JS

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by introducing a variable that determines how the `index` will change (+1 or -1). The different delay is just a different argument to `setTimeout`.

I would also suggest converting some global variables into function parameters: that way they are better (more narrowly) scoped. The change that these variables get, can be managed by what you let `setTimeout` pass on to the next call.

Here is how that could work:

```js
const texts = ['Salesforce Consultant', 'Developer', 'Writer'];
const speed = 110;
const pause = 800; // <--- the longer delay between text direction changes

function typeWriter(i=0, index=1, direction=1) {
  let displayed = texts[i].slice(0, index);
  document.querySelector("#demo").textContent = displayed;

  if (displayed.length >= texts[i].length) { // start removing after pause
    setTimeout(() => typeWriter(i, index-1, -1), pause);
  } else if (displayed.length === 0) { // go to next text after pause
    setTimeout(() => typeWriter((i+1) % texts.length), pause);
  } else { // continue in the current direction
    setTimeout(() => typeWriter(i, index+direction, direction), speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. However it is giving me a null error since I have nothing in `<p></p>`  - this is where text is going to be typed via the JS: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null at typeWriter (portfolioScript:7)
    at portfolioScript:18`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the content of your `<p></p>`. However the `id` attribute of the target element should of course be `demo`, so if it is *that* element, it should be `<p id="demo"></p>`. It was set correctly in your question. You can see that it runs fine in the snippet that I provided.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the id is set to "demo" in my code as well. However, I am developing on  the database Salesforce where you can create webpages, so it might interpret some JavaScript different..

In my code above I have a `<p></p>` wrapped in a `<div>` element - does this affect it at all?

Comment: No, the only important thing is that the element has the `id="demo"` attribute, and that *no other* element has this same `id` attribute value. Even if the webpage is generated by some tool, eventually you can view the source in your browser and see exactly what you get. Possibly the script is running before the page has loaded. Make sure to include the script at the *bottom* of your page.

Comment: You can also try to replace the last line of the code with `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => typeWriter());`. If then it works, it means your script is executing before the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I added that line, but it appears the error is with the `textContent` method - https://i.stack.imgur.com/02elc.png
Which is strange since we are already setting the value to that as var `displayed`

Comment: I cannot see from a screenshot what is happening. Please provide a fiddle. BTW: the error means that `document.querySelector("#demo")` is `undefined`, which means there is no element with `id` "demo" at the moment this script executes. Either it runs before the document is complete, or there is just no element with that ID. I cannot really help you unless you provide a runnable fiddle (like on jsfiddle) that shows the error when run, because (as you can see) it runs without issues in my answer.

Comment: Got it, I have a `<p id="demo">` in my HTML - am I referring to it correctly? In the mean time I will try providing a fiddle

Comment: So it appears to work in fiddle, and in a normal HTML site, but strangely does not in a Salesforce site - https://jsfiddle.net/patriciajlim/8djemh9y/22/

I'll have to switch over to Salesforce Stack to see what's up, but thanks for your help!